# How to test component that render HOC or mock HOC in that component?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, higher-order-components

I've got a HOC component.

```
const SectionComponent = (ComponentToWrap) => {
  return function ComponentToWrapWithLoading({...props}) {
    const { isLoading, isLoaded, icon, title } = props;
    if (!isLoading && isLoaded ) 
      return (
        <div>
          <SectionHeading icon={icon} title={title} />
          <ComponentToWrap {...props} />
        </div>
      );
    if (isLoading) 
      return (<Loader />);
    return null;  
  };
};

export default SectionComponent;
```

that i'm using in react component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import SectionComponent from '../../UI/section/Section'
import { faDumbbell} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import TableWrapper from '../../UI/table/Table-wrapper';

const SectionLoadingComponent = SectionComponent(TableWrapper);

export class TrainingsList extends Component {


  componentDidMount() {
    const {fetchTrainings} = this.props;
    fetchTrainings();
  }

  getTableColumns() {
   ...
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoading, isLoaded, data } = this.props.trainings;
    const columns = this.getTableColumns();
    return(
      <div> 
        <SectionLoadingComponent 
          isLoading={isLoading} 
          isLoaded={isLoaded} 
          title='Lista ćwiczeń'
          icon={faDumbbell}
          data={data}
          columns={columns}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

}

My problem is that I don't know how to mock SectionLoadingComponent in unit test
I've tried to used react test-renderer, but the component is not rendering.
I'll be very grateful for some hints and tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue**

The issue is this line:

`const SectionLoadingComponent = SectionComponent(TableWrapper);`

With this setup it is impossible to mock `SectionLoadingComponent` since it is evaluated when `TrainingsList` is imported and its value is always used to render every instance.  Even trying to mock it by mocking `SectionComponent()` does nothing since `SectionLoadingComponent` has already been created by the time any mocking code can run.

**Solution**

Instead of calling `SectionComponent()` in `TrainingsList`, call it within `Table-wrapper` and export the result.

Then use the export from `Table-wrapper` directly in the `render()` of `TrainingsList`.

With this setup you can mock the export of `Table-wrapper` in your unit tests and when the `render()` of `TrainingsList` runs it will use the mock.

Comment: Yes, that was is :), also had a bug in exporting class not as default.